# pragma ignored in g++ and clang

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm, pragma

I would like to disable specific known warnings in C++ code coming from a library header when compiling my own code. There are clang and gcc specific methods for disabling the warnings. The way this is done is almost identical.

For [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-local-typedefs"
#include <library.h>  
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

For [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-local-typedefs"
#include <library.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Is there a clean way to suppress these warnings that is portable across clang and GCC?

Comment: These pragmas suppress completely different diagnostics.

Comment: I edited the  post so that they suppress the same thing.

Comment: Why can't you use `#if` conditionals?

Comment: `#if` conditionals are an option, but on what conditions? Do I just special case each compiler using a predefined [macro](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) every time I want to suppress a specific warning?

Comment: Clang also recognizes `#pragma GCC`, so just use `#pragma GCC` if you want to be portable. Your link even mentions that...

Comment: The typical solution is to define MACROs to suppress these warnings using _Pragma. Other answers on stackoverflow already show how to do this.
clang and gcc understand _Pragma, MSVC requires __pragma (MSVC 16.6 with /Zc:preprocessor also understand _Pragma.

Comment: Why not just optionally remove problematic option in Makefile depending on compiler version?